# Displaying true output, not stored address

Tags: python, ipython

When I ran a code in IPython QTConsole :

-->zip([2,4],[3,1])

I expected it to output [[2,3],[4,1]], but instead it shows

-->

, something like storing address. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unfortunately, you can't.

The reason is that `zip` doesn't always get sequences as arguments.  Sequences have a known order, and can be iterated over as many times as you want.  Sometimes zip can get generators, where you actually *don't know the order, or even how many items are in it up front.*

### However,

in your specific case, you can do

```
list(zip([2,4],[3,1]))
```

To get what you want.  If you're only going to iterate over the zipped thing once, you shouldn't call `list` on it, because then you've done a lot of unnecessary work.  It's more efficient to just iterate over the zipped thing.